# How to access a slice of a tuple which is nested in dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have nested a tuple in a dict like so

```
record = {1: ('kg', '2003, 06, 05', 12)}
record[2] = ('kg', '2008, 06, 05',40)
```

I need to add all the kg values of all tuples in the dict, but I have no idea how to access the values 12 and 40.

Comment: do you mean that you want the sum of all values from a specific position in your dict?

Comment: @ahed87 yes, but to be more specific, I only want to sum all the values of the last value in each tuple. In this case being 12 and 40. I intend on having a dict with 20 or so keys at most. Just need to sum specific values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```py
    record = {1: ('kg', '2003, 06, 05', 12)}
    record[2] = ('kg', '2008, 06, 05',40)
```

We then have

```py
   record = {
       1: ('kg', '2003, 06, 05', 12),
       2: ('kg', '2008, 06, 05',40)
   }
```

So you can do `sum([t[-1] for t in record.values()])`

The `values` method returns an iterable of all the values of the dict. `sum` just sums all elements of an iterable.

This list comprehension just does: "for each tuple in the values of record, add to the list the last object of the tuple"

We get `sum([12, 40])` and so it makes `52`

EDIT: Using `-1` always returns last object and will work on any length

Comment: thank you, that works beautifully. =) 
Also I learned how to represent example dicts better in a question (looking at your example of a dict named record)

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
record: {1: ('kg', '2003, 06, 05', 12), 2: ('kg', '2008, 06, 05', 40)}
kg_sum = 0
```

1. Get all values of the dict by calling *values()* function which returns list of tuples

`record_values = record.values() # [('kg', '2003, 06, 05', 12), ('kg', '2008, 06, 05', 40)]`

2. Iterate through all values (tuples) one by one from record_values and access the last element of the tuple (required kg value) and add it to *kg_sum*

```
for record_value in record.values():
    kg_value = record_value[-1]
    kg_sum += kg_value # equivalent to kg_sum = kg_sum + kg_value
```

Comment: while your answer is helpful, and will certainly get the job done, @FrenchMasterSword answered it better. Without having to iterate through the all the values. Which is cleaner, and faster =)

Thank you for the effort though =)